# Why do StackViews not have intrinsic content size?

Tags: swift, uistackview

I've always wondered why UIStackviews don't have an intrinsic content size? What is Apple's reasoning for not having them calculate the intrinsic content size like a normal View does?

I use stackViews in autoresizing tableView cells, and I usually have to custom subclass the StackView to make the intrinsic content size be calculated correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It does has an intrinsic content size for distribution type `.fill` but this needs the subviews to have intrinsic content size like label and button , otherwise give them a height , also make sure that you hook constraints properly from top to bottom inside the cell